# java RSA Multiple Encryption

Tags: java

I encrypt my message with a symmetric key and the symmetric key itself has to be further encrypted with different RSA public keys. When I tried to implement the above I got the following error:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: The input was invalid: Invalid input length.
        at com.rsa.shareCrypto.j.hD.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
        at wrap1.main(wrap1.java:69)
```

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

i need to do something like this 
[[[[key]PK-A]PK-B]PK-C], where PK-A = Public key of A, similarly PK-B and PK-C.

Below are the codes that i tried
here are the codes

`String InitialKey = "2011BCSChampionA";`

```
byte[] initkey = InitialKey.getBytes();
// First level encryption of the key
```

`KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");`

```
keyGen.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keypair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = keypair.getPublic();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(initkey);
// Second level of encryption
KeyPairGenerator keyGen1 = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen1.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keypair1 = keyGen1.genKeyPair();
PrivateKey prvKey = keypair1.getPrivate();
PublicKey pubKey = keypair1.getPublic();
Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
byte[] cipherData_new = cipher1.doFinal(cipherData);
```

Comment: `Is there a way to solve this problem ?` If you post your code too, most definitely yes!

Comment: Does your encryption algorithm require block length that are mod 8? I seem to remember this about java...

Comment: i have given the codes i tried

Answer (score 2):

Either you should pad your data to satisfy the encryption algorithm requirements or you should create the instance of `Cipher` class pointing the padding to use, e.g.:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

As you need to use asymmetric keys then initialize your cipher the following way:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

Comment: i have to use asymmetric algorithm like RSA. Its kind of similar to Onion protocol.

Comment: i suppose its PKCS1Padding. i tried cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"); i still get the following error

javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: The input was invalid: Invalid input length.


i need to do something like this 
[[[[key]PK-A]PK-B]PK-C] where PK-A = public key of A, similarly PK-B, PK-C
i do this layered encryption and then i decrypt from the outer wall.